# Can I install GPS navigation system in Nissan B15?

Tags: nissan, dashboard, modification, gps, sunny

I'm somewhat sedan enthusiast, and while I'm working in some asian countries, I've got my attention on little old Nissan Sunny car. model name is B15 Sunny. This is the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Sunny#B15_(1998%E2%80%932006)) link I found for the car. I intend to use this for few more months and I'm planning to make a gift with this for my local assistant when I leave. So I'm trying to do some improvements for me.

It's dashboard looks like below picture. I'm wondering that if can I install a GPS navigation system (with dvd player/car radio setup which should also acts as reverse camera indicator/monitor) in this car. I want to install it onto the dashboard. Few guys from here told me that they have options to install it on reverse looking mirror, covering up the mirror and replace it with Nav system+Reverse camera. 
I'm not happy about that idea because it's hard to look at and easily break your attention from the road (while driving, while reverse, it's okay.)

I'm thinking about replacing my current radio unit with this new GPS+Radio/DVD unit with moving the climate control unit further down. Is it possible to do that in this car?

And also if you guys have any other ideas, everything will be appreciated.

[image: Current view]

**=Update=**

**I'm looking for something like these.**

[image]
**Or**

[image]
**Or**

[image]

Comment: Mount something on the inside of that center box lid above the air vents.

Comment: since display unit of common system is commonly has height of 5 inches or similar, if I mounted on that lid, I might face vision discrepency and I think put stuff with more than 4(Im not sure) inches high on top of dashboard is illeagal. I'm wondering can I replace the current radio and move the climate controls down to make some space, or better idea

Comment: you asked for ideas... Also, I don't think that will change the view of the bonnet very much - does depend on how tall you are - if your eyes are only **just** above the steering well then, yes, I agree it will change the view...

Comment: @SolarMike I **do** really appreaciate your comment, anyway I'm nearly 6 ft. Im mostly worried about the legal stuff rather than other facts. Thats why Im trying to find out if there's any possibility to remove the radio unit I have now and move climate control unit further down to make some space

Comment: Put your concern about the radio / AC unit in your question instead of the rear view mirror option...

Comment: @SolarMike I updated my question little bit

Comment: Most GPS systems are in a double-din format, but there are a few out there designed for single-din spaces, where the screen slides out into position. Maybe see if you can find one of those, rather than try to move the AC system. You'll also need a fascia kit to match the curves on the dashboard; they exist for single-din equipment.

Comment: Was your car ever offered with a double DIN unit? if so then source those parts... If not then you have a **lot** more work...

Comment: @PeteCon I'm not sure if this has what you says, pardon me since I'm no expert in this area.just an enthusiast. car model is nissan sunny b15 series. I'd like to put this right below air wents and above the climate controls. I'm okay with single din space system with sliding. if it's slides into dashboard, which means it may block either climate controls or vents when it's slides into position. am I right?

Comment: @SolarMike zi'm not sure. all I know is the car's model and its nissan b15. Im just an enthusiast who recently found this car and have no mechanical or technical knowledge other than regular usage knowledge, can you please help me out?

Comment: Start here or go to Nissan own website: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Sunny

Comment: @SolarMike I tried but nothing was helpful so far :(